# Get name of file which run function/class in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to find out which file runs function/class in PHP.

I have `index.php` which includes functions/classes, than it includes other files depending on url. I wish to know which file runs function/class for debugging.

For example I have MySql class and I what to know which file used this class.

One option is to type the file name in function like `$sql->do($cmd,$fileName)`, but there are too many files so I can't change all them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace).

In your MySql class you can simply call this function, and trace the call to it's origin.